# problems with staggered labels and date/time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have problems with the placement of the labels and date/time. They are placed in a staggered way. I want them to be placed right next to each other, on a straight horizontal line. You can see the problem on the image below.

[image]

The way I want them to be placed is like this image:
[image: Image2]

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9jsjw/14/)

JQuery:

```
var monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

function addComment(commentString) {

    var container = $('#divComments');
    var inputs = container.find('label');
    var id = inputs.length + 1;

    var div = $('<div />', {
        class: 'CommentStyle'
    });

    $('<label />', {
        id: 'comment' + id,
        text: commentString
    }).appendTo(div);

    var d = new Date();
        var $fulaDate = $('<div>' + d.getDate()
            + "-" + monthNames[d.getMonth()]
            + "-" + d.getFullYear()
            + "//" + d.getHours()
            + ":" + d.getMinutes()
            + '</div>').appendTo(div);

    var $edit = $('<p />', {
        class: 'edit',
        text: 'Edit'
    }).appendTo(div);

    var $delete = $('<p />', {
        class: 'delete',
        text: 'Delete'
    }).appendTo(div);

    div.appendTo(container);

}

$('#submit').click(function () {
    addComment($('#comments').val());
    $('#comments').val("");
});
```

CSS:

```
.CommentStyle {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.edit, delete {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Do you want complete comment section to be build by community? this 6th or 7th question related to same fiddle

Comment: Agree with @Satpal Should flag this user.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker, I personally don't think about flagging user. that would not be correct. I want Adit to grow up, learn and more important don't abuse community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.CommentStyle div{

     display:inline;
}

p{
    display:inline;
    margin-left:22px;
}
```

and this to your JS:

```
$('<br/>').appendTo(div);
```

You can set the distance (in pixels) between elements just playing with `margin-left`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9jsjw/19/)

Comment: I don't want the text to be displayed inline, after the text is written I want next line. But the date/time and Edit/Delete should be inline.